# Problems with MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext in NLog

Tags: nlog

I use MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext, because I need data to flow in async calls. This is piece of my NLog.config:

```
<column name="UserId" layout="${mdlc:item=UserId}" />
```

But in some cases I need to disable flowing, and I don't know how to do it. For example, I have code that creates several threads (see comments):

```
void Run()
{
    logger.Info("Starting threads...");  // MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.LogicalThreadDictionary is called and ConcurrentDictionary is created

    (new Thread(Func1)).Start();  // both threads will refer to the same ConcurrentDictionary object and share common values, because MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext stores data in logical call context
    (new Thread(Func2)).Start();
}

void Func1()
{
    MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("UserId", "123");
    logger.Info("Some message for Func1");
}

void Func2()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    logger.Info("Some message for Func2");  // UserId will be added to the log message here (because it was added in other thread), but I don't need it
}
```

I have found dirty workaround: at the beginning of the Func2(), I call

```
CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot("NLog.AsyncableMappedDiagnosticsContext")
```

Thus, when logging occurs in Func2(), getter of property MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.LogicalThreadDictionary will create new ConcurrentDictionary and threads will have separate instances of dictionaries. It would be good to have such a functionality in MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext class. Or are there some other ways to fix problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NLog 4.3 there will be a `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Clear(bool freeDataslot)` added, see [commit](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/commit/378a1b78e79663b8f7c124dc2c19d4615a83aa3e).

But won't it make sense to use the MDC (not MDLC) in this case?

Comment: Thank you. When will NLog 4.3 be released?
It's possible to use MDC, but it will require additional coding to initialize MDC in child threads.